# Basis of a $2\times2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I find the basis for an arbitrary matrix W such that:
$$
W =\left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & a +b +c\end{pmatrix} \ \big| \ \  a ,b ,c \in \mathbb{R} 
\right\}
$$

Comment: Hmm, sure looks like $a (something) + b (something) + c(something)$. Those $somethings$ are basis vectors.

Comment: Is $W$ a matrix or a subset of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis can be given by three matrices
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
As a result any of the matrices $W$ you defined can be given by $aA + bB + cC$.
**Note**: The space defined by $W$ is a 3-D space hence 3  matrices in the basis ( linearly independent ). If say the last entry would have been an independent real  number $d$ your basis would have 4 matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A matrix of this form can be written as: $$a\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}+b(?)+c(?)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in W\iff d=a+b+c\iff\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

will these not do for basis $$\left\{  \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \pmatrix{0&1\\0&1},\pmatrix{0&0\\1&1}   \right\} ? $$